# Port c# 2.0 BL/DL and webservice/wcf code to linux (with oracle DB)

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I have this typical scenario.  I have a smartclient application built on .net 2.0 framework on windows.  The details of the application is irrelevant.  This is not a learning project but a real mid level enterprise application which I need to port.

I need to port my BusinessLayer and DataLayer to Linux (with oracle as backend).

I am only slightly aware of the MONO project
[MONO Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Has anyone did this kind of thing?  If yes please point me to the appropriate resource which will help in migrating/porting my BL/DL to Linux.

Also does MONO support WCF/webservices?  Is there any caveat to it?

Some real experience needed here with respect to

- the ease of porting/migrating
- the issues faced
- any specific challenges
- known limitation etc.

I haven't done this kind of activity.  So, any inputs w.r.t. this will be helpful and this will be really a learning exercise for me.

### EDIT:

Got one pointer 
[The Mono Migration Analyzer Tool](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

This may seem to be useful, but not in my case as I am mostly dealing with BL/DL/Services.
But may be useful for someone.  Will give this a try.

If anyone has any other resources apart from answered by me  below will also be helpful.

Comment: Just so you know, it's Mono, not MONO.

Comment: Updated link for The Mono Migration Analyzer Tool: http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following articles on codeproject which deals with porting .net application to MONO might be useful.  This was a competion arranged in partnership with "Mainsoft's Grasshopper".  Seems to be a good tool.

-[Race to Linux - Race 2: Time Tracker Starter Kit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/RacetoLinuxRace2.aspx)

-[ASP.NET TimeTracker Starter Kits Porting from Windows to Linux](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/TimeTracker_Porting.aspx)

-[Race to Linux - Race 3: Reports Starter Kit using Mono SqlServer/Firebird](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/RaceToLinuxRace3.aspx)

AND a good overall introduction for developing on MONO can be found at

[Introduction to Mono - ASP.NET with XSP and Apache](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/introtomono2.aspx)

And here's a guide to porting applications to MONO

[Guide to porting application to MONO](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_ASP.NET_Applications)

This is not a full answer to the question but just some useful resources which I found out.